# Deploying to Heroku fails: "channel 0: bad ext data"

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to push my node.js application up to Heroku from the command line, but the prompt freezes with the text `channel 0: bad ext data`. Right before it goes down, there is a very large rush of text, which appears to be several node modules' README contents.

I've tried to push quietly with the same error: `git push -q heroku master`

Is my SSH being overloaded by data? Is there a way to silence the logs as node modules are installed?

Possibly worth noting: I'm on 32bit Win7, and using the normal command prompt, not git bash or anything, although after testing the same error happens there as well.

Comment: For a new project I've just started I run into the same issue now. I have no idea what's different from other projects that deploy successfully. Did you figure it out in the meantime?

Comment: No, I was unable to figure out the source of the problem, and Heroku support was also unhelpful. Eventually, the problem just disappeared, so I'm not sure what the deal is.

Comment: I think it might have been an issue with my configuration as well. After spending countless hours trying to figure it out I gave up. And a few days later, during which I have updated the package.json multiple times, everything started to work magically. Don't know what it was in specific :(